# Firefox icon font error

Tags: wordpress, firefox, icon-fonts

[image]

Hello. Here's [my site](http://www.theheartbandits.com/). The problem is icon font is working fine on Chrome, Safari but Firefox. Could you please help.

The odd thing is it's working fine on the [temporary site](http://www.theheartbandits.com/temphome/) with the same structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Web Console actually spells it out:

```
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "FontAwesome" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed
source: http://theheartbandits.com/wp-content/themes/sonata/css/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1
```

Firefox refuses to load the font because it violates the same-origin-policy. The Webkits seem to be more lenient.

The reason your actual home does not work but your temp. home does is simple: The actual home load the stylesheets via `href='http://theheartbandits.com/...'` while the temp one uses `href='http://www.theheartbandits.com/...'` and that `www.` makes all the difference (well, different domains).

Answer (score -2):

Go to your font folder or directory and just make sure you have all the files.

Example: you might only have `fontawesome-webfontba72.svg`

You would need to add the other files, needs to look like this

```
fontawesome-webfont.eot
fontawesome-webfont.svg
fontawesome-webfont.ttf 
fontawesome-webfont.woff
fontawesome-webfontba72.svg
FontAwesome.otf
glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
```

You can find all those files at http://fontawesome.io/